# How can I disable creating Class1 / Form1 automatically while creating a project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Every time I create a project, a default class (for class library) or form (windows application) will be created automatically.
But I'd like to change the namespace first. The easier way is deleting these files and re-create later.
By this scenario, this automatically creating procedure is totally useless and brought more job to do.

How to disable this function? And ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new project to use as a template and customise it as required. Then use the [Export Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx) wizard to create a template:

[image: File \ Export Template toolbar menu]

The wizard will save the template as a ZIP file. You may open the ZIP file and further customise project properties. To change the default namespace, update **<RootNamespace>** node value in  the **{ProjectName}.csproj** file:

[image: RootNamespace node in csproj file]

You can also change the location that Visual Studio will scan for project templates in **Tools \ Options \ Projects and Solutions \ General \ User project templates location** setting:

[image: User project templates location setting]